# "'wmic.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" in nodejs and angular

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

```
'wmic.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I saw this kind of error whenever I run `ng serve --open` on my command prompt. It doesn't affect much when I run my program in Angular9, but I am just worried about this, because maybe this may cause a problem in the future.

Comment: Would you please mind some information after this time ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this a long time ago but didn't manage to put the answer here. So I solve this by updating my `Angular` and doing the `--port 1234` whenever I run that program.